# PDO insert a simple array into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, pdo

I have a form which allows multiple text boxes for users to add different question names, these are then passed to an array:

```
name="question_name[]
```

How do i go about inserting this array into my questions table using PDO and MySQL? I have tried:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions (`question_name`) VALUES (:question_name)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':question_name', $question_name);
$stmt->execute();
```

This gives me

> Array to string conversion" error.

I have tested the `print_r` statement and the results are as expected:

```
Array ( [0] => [Answer1] => [2] => [Answer2])
```

etc... depending on the amount of text boxes used.

I understand that it is to do with BindValues / BindParam / execute() statement I would just like a correct method that works and reasoning to help me learn. Thanks.

Comment: `:questions_name` != `:question_name`

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for the spot, I have changed that, the same error persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions (`question_name`) VALUES (:question_name)";
// prepare a stamemnt only once
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':question_name', $question_name);
// iterate over your POST[question_name] array
foreach ($_POST['question_name'] as $question_name) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Such a simple solution. No explanation needed really. Thank you!

Comment: @YourCommonSense That's `bindValue` bro. Do the second change and set `bindParam`.

Comment: Just realized that it was foolish edit that I made. Dunno what I were thinking of but it seems I was totally absent-minded. My apologies.